# How to implement groupby(column1,column2) in apache beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I need help in writing similar beam code in python for the following Spark sql code.

```
count_mnm_df = (mnm_df
     .select("State", "Color", "Count") 
     .groupBy("State", "Color") 
     .agg(count("Count").alias("Total")) 
     .orderBy("Total", ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward mapping to above will be Beam SQL. See [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/overview/) for more information. Please see [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/sql.py) for corresponding Python transform which also contains information regarding usage. Please note that support for Python SDK is achieved through Beam's cross-language transforms support which is relatively new.

You can also consider authoring a Beam pipeline using [available Beam transforms](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/) that performs that same computation.

Note that Beam does not guarantee the order of elements of a `PCollection`.